# Is there a way to create a half pie chart with Vega-Lite?

Tags: vega-lite

I have a [pie chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQyAE4BrNKEwBPHHDQgkKqCAC+SgCZJMKVKGJJBDOBDQBtLbv3oA1IpAOTt4ALAAM5p56Bvz+gc5oAGzhALrmIHCyUGwWNLJkmiD0cDYFAGY0cIIWBnH6SjpR6ACODEiymHTWNKRmSlmCbCplFVUGDXWFXgaybAi5jmZpWbLl+XYgguQZ1es5EEhMm2iYKs6m50A) which I would like to convert to a half pie chart. I have tried different settings but I cannot get it to work. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, the idea of your answer was key, thank you. I tried to post a more detailed solution but it was deleted. I will add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a scale.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "mark": {"type": "arc", "radius2": 50},
  "data": {"values": [{"type": "+", "value": 60}, {"type": "-", "value": 40}]},
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {
      "field": "value",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "type": "linear",
        
        "rangeMax": 1.5708,
        "rangeMin": -1.5708
      }
    },
    "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "config": {"legend": {"disable": true}}
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this idea with a few tweaks: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLGgAMla9YCMS5EYDWaUJgCeOOFqRGUKZGSGo0DBAeIHAAHjgm6KoaMAQATCAAvhlKakh6UcRIggxwkagA2p4+fugA1KaFxTUALNbZVb5a-A1FJWgAbG0AutnRsjphsmRR9HD5qKAAZjRwgmpajX1K3p3oAI4MSLKYdHk0pKbQRTWgIVNwALIGUbHxXQAKAJJpmUp3ZI8kDEXnEEiAvj8sqMdII2Aklis1lodn5ttUtLI2AgDEVMtC5MtpgsQIJyHBZOtiWEIEgmKS0JgjCUoUA